# What is feminine form of "глупец"?

Tags: выбор-слова

For example, the phrase: "Глупец! Ты не ведаешь что творишь!" ("Fool! You don't know what are you doing!". How to say the same in female form?

- "Глупышка" does not sound serious (like "goosey", "silly");
- "Глупыня", "Глупица" does not sound grammatical;
- "Глупая" does sound as high-flown as "глупец" in this context...

Which term should one use?

LANG=ru:

Как сказать "Глупец! Ты не ведаешь, то творишь" про женщину? "Глупышка", "глупая" - не тот оттенок, "глупица/глупыня" - неправильно. Что лучше использовать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Глупыня** is not widely used. Google has only 1530 results for this word.

**Глупышка** is used in a different context, often to comfort and console a person, it is a tender form to say "silly":

- Глупышка, не плачь! Всё образуется!

**Глупая** would be the better option here, although it doesn't sound as bookish as глупец.

To make is sound high-flown I would put it like that:

**О, неразумная! Ты не ведаешь, что творишь!**

Comment: Глупая is an adjective.